# Issue while uploading Video of 25mb in kentico using Management API "Request body larger than maxBodyLength limit"

Tags: kentico, kentico-12, kentico-api

I am uploading 25 mb size of video using Kentico using Node.js
I have tried all the way but I am getting  "Request body larger than maxBodyLength limit"
How can i resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to [this article](https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/tips-for-uploading-and-staging-large-files) to see some web config keys that can be updated in order to allow large files to be uploaded and staged.

Specifically you will want to update the **maxRequestLength** and **maxAllowedContentLength** keys.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but how to implement same thing in Node.js or javascript?

Comment: The above is more about web server setup rather than coding. See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits/